# ¿Como generar un codigo consecutivo alfanumerico en MySQL con un prefijo?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Quiero formar la siguiente tabla

| id | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| CO001 | hola |
| CO002 | mundo |
| PA001 | hola |
| PA002 | mundo |

Entonces, quiero saber como generar el contenido incremental. Así tal cual como el de la columna ID, y que este se genere automáticamente cada vez que se haga una inserción en el campo nombre. Como se logra evidenciar, requiero que en cierto caso se genere con el prefijo CO y en otros con el prefijo PA